# Can I use one-way ANOVA for two and for three groups in order to maintain consistency across different sample types?

Tags: r, anova, t-test

TLDR: Some of my larger dataset has two levels, while some has three levels. Is it appropriate to test everything using one-way ANOVAs or should I do some as t-tests and some as ANOVAs (Welch's for both)?

I am comparing results from three different methods (M1, M2, M3) used for measuring a functional property of food. I have 10 types of samples (5 flours, 5 proteins). All of the types were measured using M1 and M3. Only the proteins were measured using M2 (method is only appropriate for proteins). The measurement could not be determined for one of the proteins using M2.

The M1 was tested in triplicate, M2 in duplicate (requires a MASSIVE amount of material), and M3 varied from 2 to 8 (two variations were tested for some samples and determined to be not significantly different, so are analyzed here together).

**The Types and Fractions are NOT factors of interest.** I am running my analysis in R and it is easier to run all of the analyses if I keep everything in a single data frame rather than in 10 different ones.

Dataset:

| Sample | Fraction | Method 1 (n) | Method 2 (n) | Method 3 (n) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Flour | 3 | - | 3 |
| 2 | Flour | 3 | - | 5 |
| 3 | Flour | 3 | - | 2 |
| 4 | Flour | 3 | - | 8 |
| 5 | Flour | 3 | - | 3 |
| 6 | Protein | 3 | 2 | 7 |
| 7 | Protein | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | Protein | 3 | - | 4 |
| 9 | Protein | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | Protein | 3 | 2 | 6 |

I'd like to keep the analysis as consistent as possible. If necessary, I can split up the results by fraction, but I'd rather not, as one of the objectives of the study is to show that Method 3 is valid for BOTH flours and proteins.

Since the data has unequal variances, I am planning to use Welch's Anova and Games-Howell post hoc tests. If I have to use t-tests for the two level ones, I will use the Welch's t-test.

I think the results will be cleaner if all 10 types used the same test.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. // Neither of the procedures `oneway.test` or `t.test` (default Welch) assumes that the $k$ or $2$ groups to have the same variance. That might make it easier to compare results of one-factor ANOVA with $k$ levels and Welch t with 2 levels.

Comment: I have to state which tests were used, and I think that having some data analyzed using one test and some data analyzed using another will be confusing for some readers. Can I report all of the results using an F-stat (regardless of the number of groups) or is that invalid? Or do I HAVE to report the t-stat for the two-group types and the F-stat for the three-group types?

Comment: Unless this is mainly an article on statistical testing: First, I think you should discuss differences between Methods and proteins--and why they may be important, if significant. Then you might briefly list the tests and P-values that led to that discussion.